# 'qRegisterMetaType' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'

Tags: c++, qt4

In my recent project ,i need to use connect between two threads.i use the type QList as parameter.

```
connect(multiDetection,       SIGNAL( detectFinished(QList<FileNode*>)),     
                      this,       SLOT( onMultiDetectFinished(QList<FileNode *>)));
```

To solve the problem "QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'FileNode *' (Make sure 'FileNode  *' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().  "    I do this :

```
typedef QList<FileNode *> FileNodePointer;  
qRegisterMetaType< FileNodePointer>("FileNodePointer");
```

FileNode is a class defined by myself .
But  it reminds "expected a declaration" when i move mouse on qRegisterMetaType. And when i run my program i get  this:
 'qRegisterMetaType' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'

Comment: If your compiler doesn't support C++11 you should insert another space after the type list: `qRegisterMetaType< FileNodePointer >("FileNodePointer")`

Answer (score 0):

1. `qRegisterMetaType<FileNodePointer>("FileNodePointer");` should be **called** once (in main, constructor etc.)
2. Make sure the types in `connect` and `qRegisterMetaType` are the same:
   `qRegisterMetaType<FileNodePointer>("FileNodePointer");` 
    and 
   `connect(multiDetection, SIGNAL(detectFinished(FileNodePointer)), this, SLOT(onMultiDetectFinished(FileNodePointer)));`

Answer (score 0):

I got the hint "expected a declaration" when I tried to use qRegisterMetaType from the global scope in my cpp file. Make sure you call it from within a method. I settled with calling it in the CTOR of the class which uses my type as an argument of one of its signals.

```
// --- file Foo.h --------------

class Foo
{
    // ...
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( Foo );

    // --- file Bar.h --------------

class Bar : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        Bar() {
            // since Bar emits Foo in its notify signal
            qRegisterMetaType<Foo>("Foo");
        }

    signals:
        void notify( const Foo& );
}
```